powershell ignore SSML directives
Trying do modify my TTS voice output by following SSML directive
<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'>
  normal text
  <emphasis level='strong'>emphased</emphasis>
</speak>

but TTS engine ignore it (pronounciation of word 'emphased' not change when changing emphasis level). Following oneliner is used from my hybrid batch script:
powershell.exe "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech; $synth = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer; $ssml = Get-Content -Path "%userprofile%\ssml.txt" -Raw; $synth.SpeakSsml($ssml)"

What am I doing wrong?

It's quite subtle with the default voice on en-US Win11, but it is there - do you hear the difference if you compare the same text with and without emphasis? eg. <speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'>this is normal text<break time='1s' /><emphasis level='strong'>this is normal text</emphasis></speak>

Your PowerShell script is attempting to use the System.Speech namespace to perform text-to-speech (TTS) synthesis from an SSML file. However, System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer in .NET does not support SSML directly. This namespace supports only a limited subset of XML-based speech synthesis, not the full SSML specification. If you need to work with SSML for more advanced TTS features, you'll typically need to use a TTS service or API that supports SSML, such as Google Cloud Text-to-Speech, Amazon Polly, or Microsoft Azure Text-to-Speech.
# Replace with your Azure endpoint and API key
$endpoint = 
 "https://<your_region>.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1"
$subscriptionKey = "YOUR_AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY"

# Read SSML from file
$ssml = Get-Content -Path "$env:userprofile\ssml.txt" -Raw

# Construct the request headers
$headers = @{
"Authorization" = "Bearer $subscriptionKey"
"Content-Type" = "application/ssml+xml"
"X-Microsoft-OutputFormat" = "audio-16khz-32kbitrate-mono-mp3"
}

# Send the request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $endpoint `
                         -Method Post `
                         -Headers $headers `
                         -Body $ssml

# Save the audio content to a file
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$env:userprofile\output.mp3", $response)


we are talking about offline console script. Ist out of its scope to use online engines.
